# can't get the second value of span

Tags: jquery, html

I have this small problem

```
<ul>
    <li><span id="test">val1</span></li>
    <li><span id="test">val2</span></li>
    <li><span id="test">val3</span></li>
</ul>
```

But when I try to get the value of the clicked span I get the value of the first one only
(when I click the second or third span I can't get the value of it ) I don't know why this is happening.

Here's the jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#test").click(function(){
         val = $(this).text();
         alert(val);
    });

});
```

Comment: Shh.. id should be unique.. :\

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy okay......(_whispered_) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Id should be unique, use class instead of it.

```
<ul>
<li><span class="test">val1</span></li>
<li><span class="test">val2</span></li>
<li><span class="test">val3</span></li>
</ul>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".test").click(function(){
         val = $(this).text();
         alert(val);
    });

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNBRU/14/)

Comment: @HamIsm does this solution solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

use class instaed of id . as id should be unique.

```
<ul>
<li><span class="test">val1</span></li>
<li><span class="test">val2</span></li>
<li><span class="test">val3</span></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".test").click(function(){
         val = $(this).text();
         alert(val);
    });

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/Gh2PK/1/)